# Account.sObjectType.getDescribe() vs Schema.sObjectType.Account

Tags: apex, describesobject, dynamic-apex, describes

What is the difference in below two lines of code for getting the `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult`?

```
// Get the sObject describe result for the Account object
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();

Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.Account;
```

Comment: There is no difference other than the starting class. It is all in how and when they are used. if you look at the debugs they both execute the same methods. Two different ways to do things. The first is a direct result of having the Object class vs the latter being the Schema class. both end up at getDescribe()

Comment: Yes both return the same thing. My doubt is the way sObjectType is used in two places. Can you please share some thoughts on the way of use.

Comment: Yes, Schema.sObjectype is from the Schema Class, Account.sobjecttype is the from Account class.

Comment: `Schema.SObjectType` is a `Type`. `Account.sObjectType` is an *instance* of that `Type`.

Comment: Thanks Eric and Adrian, That i was thinking. Thanks for clearing it.

Comment: @AndrianLarson - The returned result is the same type but is it not `technically` returning the same type from two different classes (Account and Schema). I do not believe that Account is an instance of Schema. But you are right the `sObjectType` from both classes is technically the same type. I think I am overthinking it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no difference except the latter becomes less verbose when you drop the optional `Schema.` portion. Every time you type:

```
SObjectType.Account
```

instead of:

```
Account.sObjectType.getDescribe()
```

you save 14 characters.

Here are some examples of the flexibility you have here.

```
Schema.SObjectType accountType = Schema.Account.sObjectType;
accountType = Account.sObjectType;

DescribeSObjectResult accountDescribe = SObjectType.Account;
accountDescribe = Schema.Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
accountDescribe = accountType.getDescribe();
```