# What's the difference: Schema.Account.AccountNumber vs Schema.Account.SObjectType.Fields.AccountNumber

Tags: apex

I've seen Apex code examples write out `Schema.SObjectField`-typed constants in both of these formats:

- `Schema.Account.AccountNumber`
- `Schema.Account.SObjectType.Fields.AccountNumber`

Why two different approaches?

Are there any features I'd lose by choosing the concise one instead of the long one?

I can see how the latter would be useful if stopped at the 4th piece, `Fields`, and were then iterating over its contents.  But I've seen examples where it's literally written out as a 5-part literal, and I'm not sure exactly why.

---

> Note:  Not quite the same question at [Account.sObjectType.getDescribe() vs Schema.sObjectType.Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133385/account-sobjecttype-getdescribe-vs-schema-sobjecttype-account) in my opinion.
>
> - The other two "feel" noticeably different from each other due to arriving at the same `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult` via very different "first class listed" paths, whereas I'm interested in two that "feel" noticeably redundant, yet both appear in the wild *(e.g. fflib tutorials)*.
> - Also, while I'm glad to be pointed to that thread and see that there's an answer of "nope, no noticeable difference" for *that particular* scenario that deals with `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult`s, this is about `Schema.SObjectField` *(and, again, a different set of syntaxes from that question)*.
>
> Just to be safe, I'd rather leave this question open until someone chimes in with an opinion about this particular case and whether people with the "5-part literal" approach are just being needlessly verbose, or whether there's a reason to use the "5-part literal" over the "3-part literal."
>
> Thanks so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Account.sObjectType.getDescribe() vs Schema.sObjectType.Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133385/account-sobjecttype-getdescribe-vs-schema-sobjecttype-account)

Comment: I mean, not really ... that question is about the reasons to choose between two different approaches to returning a `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult`.  I'm asking about the reasons to choose between two different approaches to returning a `Schema.SObjectField` -- and whose syntax don't even start with different outermost classes, at that.  Thanks for bringing the other post to my attention, though!

Comment: It amounts to the same thing - Schema.Account is a shortcut. It's Apex equivalent of a syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thanks @identigral -- if you'd like to make that an answer, feel free so I can accept it _(presuming no one else comes swooping in to argue with you)_.  :-)  I will use the shortcut whenever I am using a straight-up single-field literal.  \*Takes snippers to copy-pasted code from wordy tutorials\*

Comment: for what it's worth, you can even leave `Schema.` away, e.g. `Product2.language__c.getDescribe(FieldDescribeOptions.FULL_DESCRIBE)` works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real difference; the latter is just more verbose. Either way, you get a hard reference to a `SObjectField`. That hard reference is then reflected in your `SymbolTable`, and a dependency between your code and the field is persisted, blocking any deletion or renaming of that field.

Speaking of verbose, note you can drop the leading `Schema.` for either of the above approaches, unless you have a local variable or class named `Account`.