# How this method call works? 'Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isDeletable()'?

Tags: apex, class, code

I'm struggiling to understand this line of code:

```
Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isDeletable()
```

I've read on  the Apex Developer Guide that `isDeletable` is a method of the DescribeSObjectResult class that returns true if the object is deletable from the current user and false otherwise but I still don't understand the line of code mentioned above.

How the access is done if there is no reference to the DescribeSObjectResult class? I can't figure this out.

Schema is a namespace, sObjectType is a class inside the Schema namespace and Contact is an inner class of the sObjectType class without an `isDeletable` method, so the method shouldn't be callable because it doesn't exsist in the Contact class and there's no reference to the DescribeSObjectResult class, but the code works. Where am I wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: This would be helpful to understand:- [Account.sObjectType.getDescribe() vs Schema.sObjectType.Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133385/account-sobjecttype-getdescribe-vs-schema-sobjecttype-account)

Comment: @sanketkumar Thank you, it helped !

Answer (score 2):

`Schema.sObjectType.<sObjectName>` is a shortcut for `Schema.<sobjectName>.sObjectType.getDescribe()`. You can prove this to yourself:

```
System.assert(sObjectType.Contact == Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe());
```

Also, You can prove that it is indeed a DescribeSObjectResult:

```
Object o = sObjectType.Contact;
System.assert(o instanceOf DescribeSObjectResult);
```

This syntax was added a number of releases ago in order to provide a more concise syntax to get object and field describes when you already know the name of the sObject.

> Contact is an inner class of the sObjectType class without an isDeletable method

This is where you went wrong. It does indeed have this method available.

Note that this is different than, for example, `Contact.sObjectType`, which describes a sObjectType of the Contact object. This is a simple token that can be used to create a new sObject in memory:

```
Contact contactRecord = Contact.sObjectType.newSObject();
```

Which is typically used when dynamcially creating sObject objects in memory.

Comment: Thank you, very useful !